# vite lazy import multilevel directory

Tags: import, vite, lazy-evaluation

When I take `"parent/son1"` as the argument

```js
  // This is working fine
  const dynamicImport = (name: string) => {
    const allStr = `../views/${name}/index.tsx`;
    const DI = lazy(() => import(allStr));
    return <DI></DI>;
  };
```

```js
  // An error occurred on this
  // Error: Unknown variable dynamic import: ../views/parent/son1/index.tsx
  const dynamicImport = (name: string) => {
    const DI = lazy(() => import(`../views/${name}/index.tsx`));
    return <DI></DI>;
  };
```

I want to know why?
I'm using this framework `react-router-dom v6`

https://github.com/vitejs/vite/issues/4945
https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#how-it-works